# Customize the position of `geom_rug`

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a working example

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(926)
df <- data.frame(expression = rnorm(900),
                 time = c(rnorm(300), rnorm(300, 1, 2), rnorm(300, 2,0.5)),
                 membership = factor(rep(1:3, each = 300)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = expression, fill = membership)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, size = 3) + 
  geom_rug(data = subset(df, membership ==3),  sides = "b", color = "green", length = unit(1.5, "cm")) +
  geom_rug(data = subset(df, membership ==2),  sides = "b", color = "blue", length = unit(1, "cm")) +
  geom_rug(data = subset(df, membership ==1),  sides = "b", color = "red") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.3, 0))
```

[image]

My hope is something like

[image: this].

Note that I know the options of `outside = TRUE`, `side = "tb"` out there. But placing all rug plots at the bottom is what I really hope for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geom_rug` is designed to be drawn at the margins of a plot. It's probably best to use `geom_point` with a custom symbol in this case:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = expression, fill = membership)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, size = 3) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = -as.numeric(membership) - 2.5, color = membership), 
             shape = "|", size = 8) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -3) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-2, 0, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: A very neat way to accomplish that! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the vertical line through the circle in the legend?

Comment: I think you should be able to add the argument `key_glyph = draw_key_blank` to the second geom_point

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the position of `geom_rug()` can be easily customised. I'd recommend to use `geom_segment()` instead to draw the rugs like you'd want them.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
set.seed(926)
df <- data.frame(expression = rnorm(900),
                 time = c(rnorm(300), rnorm(300, 1, 2), rnorm(300, 2,0.5)),
                 membership = factor(rep(1:3, each = 300)))

# Helper variables
limits <- range(df$expression)
step   <- diff(limits) * 0.1
size   <- 0.45 * step

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = expression, fill = membership)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, size = 3) + 
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      colour = membership,
      xend = time,
      y    = limits[1] - as.numeric(membership) * step + size,
      yend = limits[1] - as.numeric(membership) * step - size
    )
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! I learned something new today.